# Catch timeout error, keep program running Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

My example is trivial. I the real scenario I want to catch connection timeout (in case the internet connection has been lost), so the program is not terminated (the internet connection may come back eventually). I was able to reproduce my problem in simple snippet:

```
setInterval(async () => {
  try {
    setTimeout(() => {
      throw new Error('something bad happened');
    }, 2000);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(`Cought`); // THIS CODE IS NEVER REACHED
  }
}, 5 * 1000);
```

My program crashes and node process is terminated. I DONT want this. How to catch the error so the program keep running?

I am trying to run this on Node.js `v8.11.4`

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
process.on('uncaughtException',(err)=>{
  console.log(err);
})
```

Comment: Thank you. It really works, \But isn't really there a more elegant way? I mean, I want to catch only this exception not all.

Comment: you can explore https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors